# C# regex nth character not in list or string end

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to check if the 4th letter in a string is not s or S using the following regular expression.

`Regex rx = new Regex(@"A[2-6][025][^sS].*");`

In Addition I want corresponding three letter strings to match (e.g. "A30").
Unfortunately the Match check returns false.
Does someone know what I'm doing wrong and how I can alter my regex?

`rx.Match(test).Success`

Comment: What is not working, it seems to be working in https://regex101.com/r/yVe3U8/1

Comment: Please provide example input which should match but does not match.

Comment: If just `A30` is also valid `^A[2-6][025](?:$|[^sS].*)` https://regex101.com/r/BkCTgo/1 Note that `[^sS]` can also match a newline.

Comment: `^A[2-6][025](?:[^sS].*)?$` probably.

Comment: In regex101 my solution is indeed already working but not in C#. The comment from @Thefourthbird works for me. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
^A[2-6][025](?:[^sS].*|)$
```

Note the non-capturing group part:

```
(?:[^sS].*|)
```

This matches a character that is not `s` or `S`, followed by any number of characters **or** an empty string.

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/SO7O0h/1)

Comment: This regex would be a matche for A30S, which I don't want.

Comment: [No it wouldn't](https://regex101.com/r/PE3mLm/1). Maybe you want to apply an end of line anchor `$`.

Comment: Yes, that was missing. Otherwise rx.Match("A30S").Success would be true. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First you can check if there is an s or S at fourth character place with the following regex:

```
^...[sS]
```

At a second stage you want to check, if there is a combination of A and a number which can be solved with your approach:

```
A[2-6][025]
```